# Finding median time stamp in python

Tags: python, date

```
[Timestamp('2008-01-25 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2008-01-31 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2008-01-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2008-01-09 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2008-01-17 00:00:00')]
```

I have a list of timestamps in Python above. How do I find the median time stamp?

Comment: Where are you getting the `Timestamp`s from? I.e. where is the `Timestamp` class defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you work with `pandas`, this would work:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

ser = pd.Series([Timestamp('2008-01-25 00:00:00'), 
                 Timestamp('2008-01-31 00:00:00'), 
                 Timestamp('2008-01-31 00:00:00'), 
                 Timestamp('2008-01-09 00:00:00'),
                 Timestamp('2008-01-17 00:00:00')])

pd.Timestamp.fromordinal(int(ser.apply(lambda x: x.toordinal()).median()))
```

Result:

```
Timestamp('2008-01-25 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Python 3.4 or newer**, there is no need to implement your own `median` function.

The [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) package in the standard library already includes a [median](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median) function.  Batteries included!

---

so, assuming you have a sortable sequence of timestamps, you can just do:

```
statistics.median(timestamps)
```

Comment: thanks @Corey, I would have accepted your soln, except I use python 2.7 :(

Answer (score 0):

Usually timestamps are numerical values, therefore it is not too hard to calculate the (mathematical) median.

```
>>> t = [Timestamp('2008-01-25 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2012-01-25 00:00:00')]
>>> t
[1201215600.0, 1327446000.0]
>>> mid = sum(t)/len(t)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mid)
datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 24, 12, 0)
```